# PHP - Selenium server does not connect through PHPUnit_Extension_SeleniumTestCase?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I just installed the PHPUnit Selenium extensions through "pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium". The system is currently still using PHP 5.2 so I've got to use PHPUnit_Extension_SeleniumTestCase rather than PHPUnit_Extension_Selenium2TestCase. I've been trying to run the basic test given in the PHPUnit documentation:

```
<?php
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertEquals('Example WWW Page', $this->title());
    }

}
?>
```

However, test results in the test being skipped due to:

```
1) WebTest::testTitle
Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.

Z:\applications\xampplite\php\phpunit:46
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why I might be running into this problem? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a silly one. I didn't have the Selenium server up and running. If you have the same problem just make sure to download the server from the [Selenium download page](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) and then just start the jar before attempting the test.